# How to force users unregister service worker?

Tags: reactjs, service-worker

I had a ReactJS webserver running with a domain. Recently, I've re-pointed DNS to a new server ip address but some users still see the old website though I've shutdown the old server already.

I've checked the browser network inspect and surprisingly the webpage was fetched from 
Service Worker and the date was about 50 days ago.

At the moment, they aren't able to get any responses from new web server including any headers, etc. They just see old web page whether new/old web servers are running or not.
I used nginx to host both web servers.

How can I force users clear the browser cache automatically?

UPDATED: So I guess I figured out the reason exactly. My old website supported ServiceWorker while my new website doesn't. So now, I need to clear service worker of old website. What can I do here?

Comment: Here are a couple of useful/interesting resources for you: 

https://blog.hackages.io/migrating-a-service-worker-from-an-old-domain-to-your-new-domain-69236418051c

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CPP9ew4Co0M

TL;DR you can't. You'll have to deploy a NOOP service worker that unregisters the service worker.

Comment: That was very useful @olpe. However, the main problem is that my new website doesn't support ServiceWorker.

Comment: Okay, are you able to deploy a NOOP service worker anyways, that would unregister all the existing SWs?

Comment: You're great! Obviously the resources helped me much and I've fixed my issue by adding a NOOP service worker file. Thanks!

Comment: Glad I could help :)